# Essential Grid API Redraw Not Working - Custom Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

We recently updated a wordpress site & its plugins on a dev environment and we are having major issues with Essential Grid ever since.

So below is in our custom JS. It essentially is failing on the lines "essapi_19.esredraw();" with the below error in the console:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: essapi_19 is not defined"

We have tried to check the Essential grid support docs, however, they are super unhelpful.
https://www.themepunch.com/essgrid-doc/custom-css-javascript/

Below is our custom JS:

```
jQuery('.eg-washington-red-element-22, .esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();

jQuery('#test-COS .esg-entry-content .esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20-a').removeClass('eg-washington-red-element-20-a').addClass('eg-washington-red-element-20')




jQuery('body').on('click', '.eg-washington-red-element-21', function() {
  
//var divclass = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  
  
  
  jQuery('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-22, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();
  jQuery('.eg-washington-red-element-21').show();


var $Sibling = jQuery(this).siblings('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20');

  
  //console.log($Sibling)
  
  jQuery($Sibling).slideDown(0,function(){
    jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-22').show();
    jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-21').hide();
     essapi_19.esredraw();
      })
  
});
jQuery('body').on('click', '.eg-washington-red-element-22', function() {

var $Sibling = jQuery(this).siblings('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20');


  
    jQuery($Sibling).slideUp(0,function(){
    jQuery('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-22, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();
    jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-21').show();
  essapi_19.esredraw();
   })
  
});


//// FIXES LOAD MORE ISSUE - START

jQuery('body').on('click', '.esg-loadmore', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    essapi_19.esredraw();
    jQuery('.eg-washington-red-element-22, .esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();
    
    jQuery('#test-COS .esg-entry-content .esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20-a').removeClass('eg-washington-red-element-20-a').addClass('eg-washington-red-element-20');
    
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.eg-washington-bblue-element-21', function() {      
      
      jQuery('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-22, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();
      jQuery('.eg-washington-red-element-21').show();
      var $Sibling = jQuery(this).siblings('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20');
      //console.log($Sibling)
      jQuery($Sibling).slideDown(0,function(){
        jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-22').show();
        jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-21').hide();
         essapi_19.esredraw();
      })
      
    });
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.eg-washington-red-element-22', function() {

    var $Sibling = jQuery(this).siblings('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20');
        jQuery($Sibling).slideUp(0,function(){
        jQuery('.esg-content.eg-washington-red-element-20, .eg-washington-red-element-22, .eg-washington-red-element-20-a').hide();
        jQuery(this).siblings('.eg-washington-red-element-21').show();
        essapi_19.esredraw();
       })
      
    });
    }, 2500);
});
//// FIXES LOAD MORE ISSUE - END
```

Then the below is provided by ESSGrid to us for the API call.

[image]

Please can someone assist. We are not sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: On a side note, we recently found that the "Deep Linking" setting on ESSGrid sometimes causes issues. We have made sure that this is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out that if you migrate a site containing the Essential Grid plugin, using a tool, it auto adds and _1 (or whatever other number) after the essapi_19 selector part.

So the new redraw code would be "essapi_19_X.esredraw();"

This can be found using the dev tools in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I added the equivalent of _19 at the end of the my similar code to fix this "essapi_19_19.esredraw();"

Dont remember why that works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30268819)

Comment: Thanks, yeah figured out that if you migrate the site using a tool it auto added and _1 (or whatever other number) to after the essapi_19.